# Embed element is not supported in my latest firefox browser

Tags: html

i just want to play the audio only when mysite home is opened. if any other pages is clicked it shouldn't play. i use the below code. it works fine in Google Chrome and IE also. It doesnt work in Firefox Present version. Please Help me.

```
<embed src="player/paata-ronibarni.mp3"
    loop="true" 
    autoplay="true" 
    width="0" 
    height="0">
</embed>
```

Comment: are you using flash player for it or html 5 ?

Comment: @Nomi — no, he's using `<embed>`

Answer (score 2):

```
<audio controls>  
   <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Firefox does not support the playing of MP3 files. Your best alternative is to also encode it in the OGG format.You only want to provide an MP3 file, then you need to use a Flash player to play the MP3 file in Firefox